# How to parameterize variables in a React Webpack app for different environments?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm working on a React web app which was created by `create-react-app` and I am getting ready to deploy it.

The issue is, for development, the app uses the api instance running on my dev environment (localhost:{api-port}) but for the deployed app this should point to the server api instance (api.myapp.com).

Currently the host is just a variable in my networking component:

```
const hostname = 'localhost:9876'
```

I plan on using webpack to generate the static files which will be served by the production front-end, and I would like to continue developing using `npm start` as set up by `create-react-app`.

What would be the correct way to set up my project such that the host can be set automatically to the correct value based on whether I'm running the dev server or building for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution is to check against `process.env.NODE_ENV` like this:

```
const hostname = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "localhost:9876" : "localhost:6789";
```

You may need to force the environment variable to be present in your Webpack configuration file using the `DefinePlugin` like this:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
      NODE_ENV:JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development")
    }
  })
]
```

---

An alternative solution might be to use the [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) package and provide your hostname string as a configuration parameter. config will inherit configurations from files based on the current NODE_ENV. It will start by using configuration from a default.json file, then override it with a development.json, or production.json, depending on your environment.

Note that you'll need for the config files to be copied to your output directory using [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely many ways you could achieve that. One of those solutions would be to use webpacks's `DefinePlugin`. In your plugins section in webpack configuration you would add something like this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  API_HOST: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? JSON.stringify('localhost:8080')
    : JSON.stringify('api.com')
}),
```

That creates a global variable `API_HOST` available everywhere in your codebase, which you can use. You can read more about the `DefinePlugin` here https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

you could use a relative path when you make any request to your api server instead of calling the full url for your app.

and for your development you could add a proxy property to your package.json file:

```
{
...
"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
      "target" :"http://localhost:9876"
  }
 }
}
```

so whenever you make any request that prefixed with `/api` will be redirected to `http://localhost:9876/api` this is just in the development but in the production if you make a request prefixed with `/api` it won't be redirected it will be served normally because the proxy is just available in the dev server coming with `create-react-app`.